# delimeters having same colours

Tags: php, syntax, editor

hi I want to know that is there any environment or php editor in which pair of delimiters show the same color. So that it may be helpful o avoid error during execution of complex programs?

Comment: Notepad++ (to a certain degree)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Notepad++, its free and handy to use
[notepad-plus-plus.org](http://notepad-plus-plus.org)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of text editor that can solve your problem..
but for me, Notepad++ is already enough